# NoMethodError in Pages#new undefined method `pages_index_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I'm trying to generate a form using the form_for helper in RoR but I am encountering what seems to be a routing error. Here are the relevant files:

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  devise_for :models

  root to: 'pages#home'
  resources :pages
end
```

**controllers/pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @pages = Pages.all
  end

  def show
    @page = Pages.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @page = Pages.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @page = Pages.find(params[:id])
    @page.update(page_params)
    redirect_to page_path
  end

  def new
    @page = Pages.new
  end

  def create
    page = Pages.create(page_params)
    redirect_to page_path(page.id)
  end

  private

  def page_params
    params.require(:pages).permit(:name, :content)
  end

end
```

**views/pages/new.html.erb**

```
<h1>Créer une fiche</h1>

<%= form_for @page do |g| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Titre de la fiche</label>
        <%= g.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Contenu de la fiche</label>
        <%= g.text_area :content, class: 'form-control', size: "60x12" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= g.submit "Ajouter la fiche", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<a href="<%= pages_path %>" class="btn btn-primary">Revenir à la liste des fiches</a>
```

I can't see what's wrong, still the outputt is :

[image: Displayed error on Mozilla]

The same form is working in **views/pages/create.html.erb**
If I remove the form and try to directly dump `@page` with `<%= @page %>` it returns `#<Pages:0x000055de2b6a2b10>`

Comment: I can see from your `routes.rb`  that you `root to: 'pages#home'` but I can't see action in the `pages_controller` holding that name. Do you have a view at least called `home.html.erb`

Comment: Yes I have `home.html.erb`, `index.html.erb`, `show.html.erb`, `edit.html.erb`, `new.html.erb`, all working except `new.html.erb`

Comment: Why is your model `Pages` plural?

Comment: Also - do you have some gems which can interfere with how `form_for` "guesses" the url for the form?

Comment: @meta because of my class. And I don't think that any gem is interfering because of the same form_helper working in the `edit.html.erb` page

Comment: Can you show us the code of `Posts` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the url manually for  the form.

```
<%= form_for @page, url: pages_path, method: :post do |g| %>
```